# Need to reverse php regex and see what needs to be matched

Tags: php, regex

I am not very good in RegEx and saying that I am editing a website written in php. One of it's functions are failing because of this regex:

```
preg_match("/^minus\((\-?[\d\.]+)\)$/i",$val,$m)
```

I know it should be something like `minus()` but it doesn't seems to find any matches as I can't figure it out what needs to be inside the brackets.

Comment: Can you add some examples

Comment: Its the regex for minus(-1231) or minus(12312) any length of numeric only no alphabet or special char other than - allowed

Comment: Enter it at regex101.com, it will explain what it matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is meant to match something like this:

```
minus(0.12)
minus(-0.12)
minus(.12)
```

However it is inaccurate, since it would also match:

```
minus(0.1.2)
```

Correct would be:

```
/minus\(-?\d*(\.\d+)?\)/
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/zN5xI8/1